# How can Mesos / Kubernetes / Azure be used to scale up and down available VMs?

Tags: azure, workflow, kubernetes, mesos

Does Mesos or Kubernetes provide the tooling to dynamically allocate/de-allocate virtual machines?

I need to build a workflow engine that has a highly variable load and a mixture of short and long running tasks.  For example, at 9am I might need to run 10,000 jobs with 500 taking 4 hours to run and the rest taking 5 minutes.  And then at 10 am I need to only run 600 short jobs.

If I'm running on Azure (my preferred cloud environment) can Mesos or Kubernetes dynamically scale up or scale down the available VMs in a cluster to match demand?  And can it do so intelligently so long running jobs wont be interrupted?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of an auto scaler for DCOS/MESOS in azure. Here is a github repository for making an auto scaler inside of an ACS kubernetes cluster though.
https://github.com/wbuchwalter/Kubernetes-acs-autoscaler

As for how the code works. It is a tool built using the az cli to tell the ACS service to scale up and down nodes, using az acs scale command. Looking at the code it has aspirations to  to drain all connections then pods from the node using kubectl, but it doens't appear to currently do so.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15754729)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I'll do better next time. This time I actually don't know the internals of the autoscaler all that well so I didn't want to misrepresent it. will edit in a little more detail on how it works.

Answer (score 2):

As I personally don't use Azure I can't give you a "production" insight, but as I understand [Azure supports auto-scaling](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale/#automatically-scale-an-application-running-web-roles-worker-roles-or-virtual-machines) either via average CPU usage or message queue size. Refer to the docs for what is possible with Azure if you want to follow the "manual" way.

For the Mesos case, I think the CPU usage pattern could be utilized to automatically start new Mesos Slaves/Agents if certain limits are hit. As far as I know pure Mesos cannot start other VMs itself, which means auto-scaling has to be done via the cloud provider's interfaces.

If you want to use DCOS, there is a EAP for [DCOS on Azure](https://mesosphere.com/azure/), which requires a signup. From what I understand, DCOS should be able to interact with the cloud provider's interfaces, meaning that it should be able to scale automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes doesn't really have auto-scaling yet but you could do it "manually" by monitoring the specific api's (number of requests per second) and have it call the specific Azure scale up/down api's.